# How to save object in mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to use object to combine admins, but I cant figure out. Here is the schema and code

```
UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type:String },
  owner : {
    Admin       : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    }
});
```

And saving function:

```
user.name = 'nerkn';
user.owner={ Admin     :new ObjectId(Adminid)} // this is from another user


el  = req.db.model('Users')(user)
el.save((err)=>{console.log(err)})
console.log('el', el)
```

when I check name is saved but owner.Admin is not.

Answer (score 0):

You should mark as modified nested objects before save

```
el.markModified('owner');
```